# Opening Outlook new email windows using jQuery using loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email, outlook

I have a list of records on a webpage (say html table).

```
<table> 
    <tr> 
        <th>checkbox</th> 
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
<tr> 
<td><input type="checkbox" name="email[]">1</td>
<td>1</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="email[]">2</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="email[]">3</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>Austria</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="email[]">4</td>
<td>4</td>
<td>UK</td></tr>
</table>
```

Now, When I select different/all checkboxes and click on a button.

It should open new outlook windows separately for each record.
SO if I select all 4 checkboxes, than it should open 4 different new Email windows.
I have already referred so many questions here. But could not figure it out.

The biggest problem is that I can run the loop. But every time it CAN NOT open different windows. Sometimes it opens only 1/2 windows. I guess is the problem of loop and Settimeout.

Here is my code:

```
    function sendMails() {
        sendMail_table.$('input:checked').each(function (i, value) {
            (function (that, m) {
                var t = setTimeout(function () {
                if (m.checked) {
                    var rowIndex = sendMail_table.row($(m).closest('tr')).data();
                    var party_name = rowIndex[6];
                    var find = $('#party_email_data td').filter(function () {
                        return $(this).text() === party_name;
                    });
                    emails = party_email_data.row(find.closest('tr')).data();
                    email_add = emails[1];
                    email_cc = emails[2];
                    wnd = window.open("mailto:email_id?subject=hello hi&body=dfdsf", 
     "_blank", "sdf" + i);
                }
            }, 1500);
        })(this, value);
    });
}
sendMails();
```

So, herecolumn names or variable names are not important for me for getting solution. I AM FACING PROBLEM IN LOOP AND SETTIMEOUT. All windows DO NOT open as they should be.

Though loop runs number of times as it should be, but some how only1/2 new email outlook windows open. Which is wrong. I guess this happens because JS loop does not wait for response or anything else.

I hope you all understood my problem.
Let me know if anything else to be mentioned or clarified.

I need this solution. Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: here is the sample html table :<table>
  <tr>
    <th>checkbox</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>name</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="email[]">1 </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="email[]">2</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="email[]">3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="email[]">4</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr></table>

Comment: Can you post it in your question?

Comment: And where is the variable `sendMail_table` defined?

Comment: What is `party_email_data`?
Whom are you trying to send a mail and what content should it have?

Comment: Hello everyone, i have posted html code. And yes sendMail_table is defined as a global variable with id of html table. In party_email_data is the another global variable for another table to get other various values. THE ISSUE IS IN "Settimeout" concept. You can check this whole code by taking static value whenever possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the email pop-up didn't work well for me either when it was inside the timeout.
What did work, is putting the email popup outside of the timeout.

```
function sendMails() {
  sendMail_table.$('input:checked').each(function(i, value) {
    (function(that, m) {
      var t = setTimeout(function() {
        if (m.checked) {
          var rowIndex = sendMail_table.row($(m).closest('tr')).data();
          var party_name = rowIndex[6];
          var find = $('#party_email_data td').filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() === party_name;
          });
          emails = party_email_data.row(find.closest('tr')).data();
          email_add = emails[1];
          email_cc = emails[2];
        }
      }, 1500);
    })(this, value);
    wnd = window.open("mailto:email_id?subject=hello hi&body=dfdsf", "_blank", "sdf" + i);
  });
}
sendMails();
```

BTW, I'm not sure why you need the `timeout` there.
Also, there are more elegant ways of popping up an email dialog.

Comment: (function myLoop (i) {          
  setTimeout(function () {   
   wnd = window.open("mailto:abc@email.com?subject=hello hi&body=dfdsf","_blank","ssdfsd"+i);          //  your code here                
   if (--i) myLoop(i);      //  decrement i and call myLoop again if i > 0
    setTimeout(function () {
      wnd.close();
    },1200);
  }, 1500)
   })(6);    This works fine. And this is what exactly I want. Now I have to run this for my all selected checkboxes (may be using .each loop). Also the passed parameter's value here is "6",must be dynamic.